# MP4 Video Thumbnail create using php GD

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails, mp4

I am using GD image library to upload videos but I can not create any thumbnail, is there any way to create mp4 video file thumbnail using php gb image library?

this is my code; is it possible to entegrate ffmpeg ?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{

############ Edit settings ##############
$ThumbSquareSize        = 400; //Thumbnail will be 200x200
$ThumbPrefix            = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix
$DestinationDirectory   = 'uploads/'; //specify upload directory ends with / (slash)
$Quality                = 90; //jpeg quality
##########################################

//check if this is an ajax request
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    die();
}

// check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
{
        die('Something wrong with uploaded file, something missing!'); // output error when above checks fail.
}

// Random number will be added after image name
$RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); 

$ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])); //get image name
$ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // get original image size
$TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Temp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
$ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //get file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

//Let's check allowed $ImageType, we use PHP SWITCH statement here
switch(strtolower($ImageType))
{
    case 'video/mp4':
        break;
    default:
        die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
}

//PHP getimagesize() function returns height/width from image file stored in PHP tmp folder.
//Get first two values from image, width and height. 
//list assign svalues to $CurWidth,$CurHeight
list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);

//Get file extension from Image name, this will be added after random name
$ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
$ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

//remove extension from filename
$ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName); 

//Construct a new name with random number and extension.
$NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
$pageurl = 'http://'.@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].strtr(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '\\', '/').'';
//set the Destination Image
$thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName; //Thumbnail name with destination directory
$DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; // Image with destination directory

//Resize image to Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName ))
{
    //Create a square Thumbnail right after, this time we are using cropImage() function
    if(!resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$Quality,$ImageType))
        {
            echo 'Error Creating thumbnail';
        }
    /*
    We have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
    We can now output image to user's browser or store information in the database
    */
$variable = <<<XYZ
<div class="kingimgupload">
<iframe src="$pageurl/uploads/$NewImageName" alt="Resized Image"></iframe>
<img src="$pageurl/uploads/$ThumbPrefix$NewImageName" alt="Resized Image">
</div>
XYZ;
echo $variable;
    /*
    // Insert info into database table!
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO myImageTable (ImageName, ThumbName, ImgPath)
    VALUES ($DestRandImageName, $thumb_DestRandImageName, 'uploads/')");
    */

}else{
    die('Resize Error'); //output error
}
}


// This function will proportionally resize image 
function         resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
//Check Image size is not 0
if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
{
    return false;
}

//Construct a proportional size of new image
$ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurWidth); 
$NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
$NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);
$NewCanves          = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);

// Resize Image
if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
{
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'video/mp4':
            imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
//Destroy image, frees memory   
if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
return true;
}

}
```

Comment: take a look at ffmpeg

Comment: but not all servers supporting ffmpeg

Comment: Sure every server support ffmpeg. What you mean, is possible a shared hosting envoirenment. Cann't imagine there is suche a environment out there, that allows movie hosting...

Comment: is it not possible with gd?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this using GD.

Take a look into the Documentation

http://php.net/manual/de/book.image.php

You have only the following `imagecreatefrom*` functions:

```
imagecreatefromgd2
imagecreatefromgd2part
imagecreatefromgd
imagecreatefromgif
imagecreatefromjpeg
imagecreatefrompng
imagecreatefromstring
imagecreatefromwbmp
imagecreatefromwebp
imagecreatefromxbm
imagecreatefromxpm
```

There Is no video format. So no, it is not possible.

Take a look at `FFMpeg` and consider this library:

FFMpeg: https://www.ffmpeg.org/

PHP Library: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/

Sure it is not installed in most of shared environments, but if you take a look into the contract of this, you will see, that video hosting is disallowed.

Sure there are other Possibility, but i can't imagine a PHP only way.

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple code:

```
$video_path = 'D:\xampp\htdocs/test.mp4';
$video_image_dir = 'D:\xampp\htdocs/';
$video_name = 'teat.mp4';
$time_in_seconds = round(1 / 2); 
exec("ffmpeg -vframes 1 -ss " . $time_in_seconds . " -i " . $video_path . " " . $video_image_dir . $video_name . ".jpg -y 2> " . $video_image_dir . $video_name . ".txt");
```

Comment: using ffmpeg is clever :-)

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible using ffmpeg.

- install ffmpeg in your server.
- check below example code.

extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

```
// $vid = realpath('./video/Wildlife.wmv');

$video_url = 'http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4';

$image_filename = 'images/' . time() . ".jpg";

$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($video_url, false);

$frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();

$capPos = ceil($frameCount / 4);

$frameObject = $movie->getFrame($capPos);

if ($frameObject) {

    $frameObject->resize(500, 250, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    imagejpeg($frameObject->toGDImage());

} else {

    echo 'error';

}
```